# Angular 7 Drag&Drop nested lists with native CDK

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular7

I am using native Angular 7 Drag&Drop provided by `@angular/cdk/drag-drop`.

Basically, I just need to create one sortable list inside another one as in the code below:

```
<div class="external-list" cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="drop1($event)">
  <div class="external-item" cdkDrag *ngFor="let item of items">
    {{item.header}}
    <div class="internal-list" cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="drop2($event)">
      <div class="internal-item" cdkDrag *ngFor="let row of item.rows">
        {{row}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*This is a very schematic example just to demonstrate the purpose.*

The problem is when I try dragging the inner items outer ones are dragged instead.

How can I solve this without resorting to 3rd-party packages?

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to use a drag handle (`cdkDragHandle` on an element inside `cdkDrag`), at least for the parent list.

https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#customizing-the-drag-area-using-a-handle

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I believe it's possible to achieve the desired behavior but this will probably require some dirty workaround with layout rework (moving child draggable elements out of parent draggable one and using `position: absolute` to place them to the right places).